# Get the name of the object passed in a byref parameter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reflection

How can I get the name of the object that was passed byref into a method?

Example:

```
Dim myobject as object

sub mymethod(byref o as object)
    debug.print(o.[RealName!!!!])
end sub

sub main()
    mymethod(myobject)
    'outputs "myobject" NOT "o"
end sub
```

I'm using this for logging. I use one method multiple times and it would be nice to log the name of the variable that I passed to it. Since I'm passing it byref, I should be able to get this name, right?

For minitech who provided the answer:

This would give you the parameter name in the method and it's type, but not the name of the variable that was passed byref.

```
using system.reflection

Dim mb As MethodBase = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()
For Each pi As ParameterInfo In mb.GetParameters()
    Debug.Print("Parameter: Type={0}, Name={1}", pi.ParameterType, pi.Name)
Next
```

If you put that in "mymethod" above you'd get "o" and "Object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's impossible. Names of variables are not stored in IL, only names of class members or namespace classes. Passing it by reference makes absolutely zero difference. You wouldn't even be able to get it to print out "o".

Besides, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @Hans Passant: "myobject"? No, it's not. It's a variable.

Comment: For logging. This is a process that will run without a GUI and I'm trying to not repeat code. If I could have gotten the variable name it would have been nice for the log. I'm just going to have to pass it to my method as a string literal now. But "No" is an answer too. Thanks.

see my question for a code example of printing "o" (I edited it).

Comment: Can this be done in PHP? Maybe that's where I remember having that kind of power lol.

Comment: @John: Not that I know of... you can use a variable by variable name using the syntax `$$varname`, but I don't know of any programming language at all that will persist variable names, not even scripting languages. You can still avoid repeating yourself by using a more descriptive name, for example `log.WriteLine(String.Format("Found {0} non-user-opened sessions", numSessions))`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could get the 'Type' of the object using reflection.

**Example: (Use LinqPad to execute)**

```
Sub Main    
  Dim myDate As DateTime =  DateTime.Now
  MyMethod(myDate)

  Dim something As New Something
  MyMethod(something)       
End Sub

Public Class Something
   Public Sub New
    Me.MyProperty = "Hello"
   End Sub
   Public Property MyProperty As String
End Class

Sub MyMethod(Byref o As Object)
   o.GetType().Name.Dump()
End Sub
```

Comment: I think he was asking for the variable name, not the name of the class that was used

Comment: Yes but as an alternate solution you could see if the Type provides information that could be used to log against. Ie DateTime came in, then an Int32 came in etc.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful but I was really looking for the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but this is your solution.  I left `(ByVal o As Object)` in the method signature in case you're doing more with it.

```
Sub MyMethod(ByVal o As Object, ByVal name As String)
    Debug.Print(name)
End Sub

Sub Main()
   MyMethod(MyObject, "MyObject")
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could create an interface, but this would only allow you to use `MyMethod` with classes you design.  You can probably do more to improve it, but as this code stands you can only set the `RealName` at creation.

```
Interface INamedObject
    Public ReadOnly Property RealName As String
End Interface

Class MyClass
    Implements INamedObject

    Public Sub New(ByVal RealName As String)
        _RealName = RealName
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly Property RealName As String Implements INamedObject.RealName
        Get
            Return _RealName
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _RealName As String
End Class

Module Main
    Sub MyMethod(ByVal o As INamedObject)
        Debug.Print(o.RealName)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim MyObject As New MyClass("MyObject")
        MyMethod(MyObject)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program is still in the same place relative to the code that made it, this may work:

```
'  First get the Stack Trace, depth is how far up the calling tree you want to go
Dim stackTrace As String = Environment.StackTrace
Dim depth As Integer = 4

'  Next parse out the location of the code
Dim delim As Char() = {vbCr, vbLf}
Dim traceLine As String() = stackTrace.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim filePath As String = Regex.Replace(traceLine(depth), "^[^)]+\) in ", "")
filePath = Regex.Replace(filePath, ":line [0-9]+$", "")
Dim lineNumber As String = Regex.Replace(traceLine(depth), "^.*:line ", "")

'  Now read the file
Dim program As String = __.GetStringFromFile(filePath, "")

'  Next parse out the line from the class file
Dim codeLine As String() = program.Split(delim)
Dim originLine As String = codeLine(lineNumber * 2 - 2)

'  Now get the name of the method doing the calling, it will be one level shallower
Dim methodLine As String = Regex.Replace(traceLine(depth - 1), "^   at ", "")
Dim methodName = Regex.Replace(methodLine, "\(.*\).*$", "")
methodName = Regex.Replace(methodName, "^.*\.", "")

'  And parse out the variables from the method
Dim variables As String = Regex.Replace(originLine, "^.*" & methodName & "\(", "")
variables = Regex.Replace(variables, "\).*$", "")
```

You control the depth that this digs into the stack trace with the depth parameter. 4 works for my needs. You might need to use a 1 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is the apparently how Visual Basic controls handle the problem.

They have a base control class that in addition to any other common properties these controls may have has a name property.

For Example:
    Public MustInherit Class NamedBase
    Public name As String
    End Class

```
Public Class MyNamedType
    Inherits NamedBase
    public Value1 as string
    public Value2 as Integer
End Class

dim x as New MyNamedType

x.name = "x"
x.Value1 = "Hello, This variable is name 'x'."
x.Value2 = 75

MySubroutine(x)

public sub MySubroutine(y as MyNamedType)
    debug.print("My variable's name is: " & y.name)
end sub
```

The output in the intermediate window should be:

My variable's name is: x